# Creating a fixed footer with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an app that uses Bootstrap. I want this app to have a footer. The footer needs to "stick" to the bottom. In other words, if the content is larger than the height of the screen, the footer should still be visible, the content goes under it. If the content takes less than the height of the screen, I still need the footer to stick tothe bottom. I tried using the [sticky footer](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/). However, that doesn't work. Currently, I am trying the following:

**[Here's My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FEiwDfdkedFqn0L7uBIA?p=preview)**

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></button>
    &nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I build a footer that permanently sticks to the bottom? I'm basically trying to build an "action bar" that is visible only when the site runs on a phone.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Bootstrap provides an example in on their site under "Getting Started"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code

```
    .footer {
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 60px;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change the footer position :

```
.footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed; /*change it*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap comes with its nav elements ready to roll as a footer.

Simply create your  element and add these classed *navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom*.

```
<footer>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p>this is your footer that sticks to the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

You can then expand on this by splitting the containing div into blocks with something like

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*the above would go* **inside** *the container div*

as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/showcaseimagery/5y14pqgv/